# CoffeeScript and the context

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to get the value `$(this)` with the context that the event was triggered, but I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

```
cants_field_hidden = document.createElement('input')
cants_field_hidden.setAttribute 'type', 'hidden'
cants_field_hidden.setAttribute 'id', 'cant_' + if id == undefined then item_id else id
cants_field_hidden.classList.add 'cant_input'
cants_field_div.append cants_field_hidden

cants_field_visible = document.createElement('input')
cants_field_visible.setAttribute 'type', 'number'
cants_field_visible.setAttribute 'placeholder', 'Porciones'
cants_field_visible.setAttribute 'name', 'ammounts[]'
cants_field_visible.setAttribute "onkeypress", calculate_carbohydrates((if id == undefined then item_id else id), (if 
carbohydrates == undefined then item_carbohydrates else carbohydrates))
cants_field_visible.setAttribute 'required', true
cants_field_div.append cants_field_visible

function calculate_carbohydrates(id, carbohydrates){
  console.log($(this))
  console.log(id)
  console.log(carbohydrates)

  var input = document.getElementById('cant_' + id)
  var total_carbohydrates = $(this).val() * carbohydrates

  input.value = parseInt(total_carbohydrates)

  var sum = 0;
  $(".cant_input").each(function(){
    sum += Number($(this).val())
  })
  $("#total_carbohydrates").val(sum).trigger('change')
  $("#total_carbohydrates_span").text($("#total_carbohydrates").val())
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant HTML please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100543/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-value-of-null)

Comment: It seems that you may have misread the error message. It does not say "Cannot set property 'val()' of null," per your title. It says "Cannot set property 'value' of null."

Comment: @JordanRunning Sorry, put the wrong error, it is already edited.

Comment: You seem to have mixed coffeescript and javascript?

Comment: Where exactly in your code is this error occuring? *getting* the value wouldn't cause an error related to *setting* the value.

Comment: @JaredSmith No, the function has a different file than just JS

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory: `Cannot set property 'value' of null`. Look at your code. Where are you setting a property named `value`? The thing you're setting the property on isn't what you think it is; it's `null`.

Comment: @JordanRunning I do not understand, I try to obtain the object value of the object with which the event was triggered, in this case it is an input and I want to obtain its value, simple.

Comment: If the error is indeed coming from the code you've posted, then that's the line it's coming from. It means that `input` is `null`, which means that `document.getElementById('cant_' + id)` returned `null`, which means no element with the given id exists.

Comment: @JordanRunning Is that you do not understand me, the variable input is another element different from the one that triggers the event ...

Comment: The variable `input` is not any element; the value of `input` is `null`. Either that or the error is coming from some other code that you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 0):

**Find a solution**

```
cants_field_visible.addEventListener "keyup", ->
    calculate_carbohydrates.call(this, "#{if id == undefined then item_id else id}", "#{if carbohydrates == undefined then item_carbohydrates else carbohydrates}")
```