# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')

Tags: angular, typescript

I know this problem has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100543/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-value-of-null), but I couldn't find an answer which could help me.
Inside a form, I have an input:

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Database Name</mat-label>
    <input [disabled]="isValueSelected_SQLite()" id="numeDB_SQLite" type="text" matInput
           placeholder="Ex: Lite_DB" name="numeDB_SQLite" ngModel required=""
           oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter DB name')"
           oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
</mat-form-field>
```

On `ngAfterViewInit` function I want to assign a value to input field:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  (document.getElementById("numeDB_SQLite") as HTMLInputElement).value = "dt";
}
```

On I open the page, I get the error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')`. I searched on browser's Elements and the field has the id `numeDB_SQLite`. I have tried to use `ngOnInit` method instead of `ngAfterViewInit`. What could I do to solve the error?

Comment: Why don't you use an ngModel?

Comment: How could I use it?

Comment: Can you put your project in stackblitz? I can modify it for you

Comment: Thank you! Ionut's solution helped me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On html:

```
         <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
                 <mat-label>Database Name</mat-label>
                       <input [disabled]="isValueSelected_SQLite()" id="numeDB_SQLite" type="text" matInput
                                    placeholder="Ex: Lite_DB" name="numeDB_SQLite" [(ngModel)]="dt" required=""
                                    oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please enter DB name')"
                                    oninput="setCustomValidity('')">
         </mat-form-field>
```

On typescript:

```
dt: string = "";  
ngAfterViewInit() { dt= "this appears on field" }
```